# Yii URL override

Tags: url, yii, path-finding

I've tweaked around my yiitestapp and was able to display what was needed by making my own function and pages in views. However, I want to link those pages I have made on the menu bar. How do I override the url pathing?

For example, this line of code:

```
array('label'=>'Manage Chemicals', 'url'=>array('%2FGetChemicals')),
```

generates the address

```
localhost/yiitestapp/index.php?r=product_try/%2FGetApparatus
```

but I need the "/" away.

Answer (score 0):

why using %2F.

```
array('label'=>'Manage Chemicals', 'url'=>array('%2FGetChemicals')),
```

You can do like this

```
array('label'=>'Manage Chemicals', 'url'=>array('/GetChemicals')),
```